# Adding Keyboard Elements To Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button here named `.togglePL` and have coded it to expand or collapse the page selectors in `#pageList`. I would like to expand or collapse the page selectors using a keyboard element of `alt + p` without having to click the button itself. I have tried researching how to do this through JS online and through questions here but with no prevail. Please find the code attached, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
// Toggle Page List
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.togglePL').click(function(e) {
        if ($('#pageList').width() == 40) {
            $('.textPL').show();
            $('#pageList').width(168);
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'192px', transform: 'none'});
             $('#pageList a').css({fontSize:'10pt'});
        }
        else {
            $('.textPL').hide();
            $('#pageList').width(40);
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'64px', transform: 'rotate(180deg)', transitionDuration:'0.3s'});
            $('#pageList a').css({fontSize:'14pt'});
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/*
 ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
*/

html > body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #555;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 40px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 background: #1b315e;
}

#navigation > .spacer {
 display: block;
 margin: 120px 0 0 0;
}

#navigation > a {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 28px 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18pt;
 color: #fff;
}

#navigation > a.active {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 2px solid #fff;
 background: #2b417e;
}

#navigation > a:not(.active):hover {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 2px solid #fff;
 background: #2b417e;
 opacity: 0.75;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 48px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #fff;
}

#navigation > .navLinks:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #2b417e;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

/* Page List */
#pageList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 168px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #2b417e;
}

#pageList > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 28px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #fff;
}

#pageList > a.active {
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #3b518e;
}

#pageList > a:not(.active):hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #3b518e;
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#pageList > .togglePL {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 192px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
-->
<html lang="en-AU"><head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
 <title>Welcome - Summit</title>
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bec3ffe91b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- External Font Stylesheet -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- External JQuery Script -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="navigation">
   <div class="spacer"></div>
   <a href="#" title="Home workspace" class="active"><i class="fal fa-home"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Learning workspace"><i class="fal fa-book"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Student management workspace"><i class="fal fa-user"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Portal workspace"><i class="fal fa-globe"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Administration workspace"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
   <div class="spacer"></div>
   <button title="Help" class="navLinks"><i class="fal fa-question-circle"></i></button>
   <button title="Quick links" class="navLinks"><i class="fal fa-bookmark"></i></button>
   <button title="Log out" class="navLinks"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
  </div>
        
        <!-- Page List -->
        <div id="pageList">
            <a href="#" title="Dashboard"><i class="fal fa-chart-line"></i> <span class="textPL">Dashboard</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Summit messages"><i class="fal fa-comments"></i> <span class="textPL">Summit Messages</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Help"><i class="fal fa-question-circle"></i> <span class="textPL">Help</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Notices"><i class="fal fa-newspaper"></i> <span class="textPL">Notices</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> <span class="textPL">Timetable</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Welcome" class="active"><i class="fal fa-hands-helping"></i> <span class="textPL">Welcome</span></a>
            <button title="Expand/collapse the page selectors [ alt + p ]" class="togglePL"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </div>
  
  </div>
        
        <script src="../JS/setting.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Internal Script -->
        
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this .on key event check the `keycode` is 80 and `altkey` pressed.And then trigger click event of the menu

```
if (e.altKey && keyCode == 80)
```

Code

```js
// Toggle Page List
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.togglePL').click(function(e) {
        if ($('#pageList').width() == 40) {
            $('.textPL').show();
            $('#pageList').width(168);
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'192px', transform: 'none'});
             $('#pageList a').css({fontSize:'10pt'});
        }
        else {
            $('.textPL').hide();
            $('#pageList').width(40);
            $('.togglePL').css({left:'64px', transform: 'rotate(180deg)', transitionDuration:'0.3s'});
            $('#pageList a').css({fontSize:'14pt'});
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        let keyCode = e.keyCode | e.which;
        if (e.altKey && keyCode == 80) {
           $('.togglePL').trigger('click')
        }
      })
```

```css
/*
 ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
*/

html > body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #555;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 40px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 background: #1b315e;
}

#navigation > .spacer {
 display: block;
 margin: 120px 0 0 0;
}

#navigation > a {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 28px 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18pt;
 color: #fff;
}

#navigation > a.active {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 2px solid #fff;
 background: #2b417e;
}

#navigation > a:not(.active):hover {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 2px solid #fff;
 background: #2b417e;
 opacity: 0.75;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 48px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #fff;
}

#navigation > .navLinks:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #2b417e;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

/* Page List */
#pageList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 168px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #2b417e;
}

#pageList > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 28px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #fff;
}

#pageList > a.active {
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #3b518e;
}

#pageList > a:not(.active):hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #3b518e;
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#pageList > .togglePL {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 192px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
-->
<html lang="en-AU"><head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
 <title>Welcome - Summit</title>
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bec3ffe91b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- External Font Stylesheet -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- External JQuery Script -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="navigation">
   <div class="spacer"></div>
   <a href="#" title="Home workspace" class="active"><i class="fal fa-home"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Learning workspace"><i class="fal fa-book"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Student management workspace"><i class="fal fa-user"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Portal workspace"><i class="fal fa-globe"></i></a>
   <a href="#" title="Administration workspace"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
   <div class="spacer"></div>
   <button title="Help" class="navLinks"><i class="fal fa-question-circle"></i></button>
   <button title="Quick links" class="navLinks"><i class="fal fa-bookmark"></i></button>
   <button title="Log out" class="navLinks"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
  </div>
        
        <!-- Page List -->
        <div id="pageList">
            <a href="#" title="Dashboard"><i class="fal fa-chart-line"></i> <span class="textPL">Dashboard</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Summit messages"><i class="fal fa-comments"></i> <span class="textPL">Summit Messages</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Help"><i class="fal fa-question-circle"></i> <span class="textPL">Help</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Notices"><i class="fal fa-newspaper"></i> <span class="textPL">Notices</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> <span class="textPL">Timetable</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Welcome" class="active"><i class="fal fa-hands-helping"></i> <span class="textPL">Welcome</span></a>
            <button title="Expand/collapse the page selectors [ alt + p ]" class="togglePL"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        </div>
  
  </div>
        
        <script src="../JS/setting.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Internal Script -->
        
 </body>
</html>
```